# Spit out data sources, and libraries used in opened program

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Is there a way to extract all the data sources and libraries used in an opened program in SAS EG?

I found the following which I am able to manipulate, but unfortunately I am unable to use Filename because of how sas is set up, and I am unable to use Filename FTP. Any ideas here?

```
   Filename inp "<path and name of the sas code/>";

   data temp;
   infile inp;
   input rec $100.;
   if index(lowcase(rec), "libname") ne 0 then output; /*check libraries */
   else if index(lowcase(rec),"filename") ne 0 then output; /*check input files*/
   else if index(lowcase(rec),"data") ne 0 and index(rec,".") ne 0 then output; /* to check the  
   permanent datasets */
   else if index(lowcase(rec),"merge") ne 0 and index(rec,".") ne o then output; /*check permanent 
   datasets used in merge*/
   run;
```

Comment: Look into PROC SCAPROC but it does require you to run the process.

Comment: That code will not work if you have any macro code and/or generated code. It's not robust enough at all to catch things.

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you know if you can export Proc Scaproc to a table instead of a file? e.g. assign it to a table in one of my libraries?

Comment: No, you'd still have to parse that file with something like what you have above, but it will be more reliable.

Comment: I got it to work. This is great! Thank you so much. I came across [this](https://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug-cn/2017/DM/PharmaSUG-China-2017-DM01.pdf) from Matt Becker and it did the trick.